# If $3x+2y=mx+ny$ for all $x$ and $y$, then must $m=3$ and $n=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

If: $$3x+2y=mx+ny$$

can $m$ and $n$ take other values than $3$ and $2$ respectively, for any real values for $x$ and $y$ except $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

If no, can you please give an easy to understand proof for a $12$th grade student? Is this something related to [Equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients)?

Comment: I'm still kinda hoping for a generalized answer that shows the intuition between Equating coefficients and the possibility to create a vector space where both sides of the equations are linearly independent subsets of the vector space

Comment: $$3x+2y=mx+yn \implies (3-m)x + (2-n)y = 0.$$  For any reasonable interpretation of the problem, $x$ and $y$ are (linearly) independent of each other, hence $3-m = 2-n = 0$.  Hence $m = 3$ and $n=2$.  Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which values $m$ and $n$ can have. If you are searching for numbers, $m=3$ and $n=2$ are the only solutions.

More generally, you can write your equation to
$mx = 3x + 2y - ny$, which is equivalent to $m=3 + \frac{2y-ny}{x} = 3 + \frac{(2-n)y}{x}$ by dividing by $x$. So you have to exclude $x=0$. 
Now you can choose an arbitrary $n$ and for a solution you have got to "fix" your $m$ with the formula above. 
Back to the beginning. If you are searching numbers, then you don't want that your solution for $m$ and $n$ depends on $x$ and $y$, so the second summand $\frac{(2-n)y}{x}$ has to be $0$, which happens, when $2-n=0$, so if $n=2$ and tehrefore $m=3$.

Comment: Why should the second summand be zero?

Comment: Because you want a solution for $m$ which is independent from $x$ and $y$. If the summand isn't $0$, $m$ would not be a "number" as solution.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

- for $(x,y)=(1,0)\implies 3\cdot 1+2\cdot 0=m\cdot 1+n\cdot 0 \implies m=3$
- for $(x,y)=(0,1)\implies 3\cdot 0+2\cdot 1=m\cdot 0+n \cdot 1 \implies n=2$

Answer (score 1):

(Of course we need to assume that $m$ and $n$ are required to be integers or the problem is utterly trivial.)

**Hint:** Say $x=1$ and $y=\sqrt 2$. If $3x+2y=mx+ny$ that says $(2-n)\sqrt 2=m-3$. *If* $n\ne 2$ then $\sqrt 2=(m-3)/(2-n)$, which is impossible because...

Comment: It may be implicit, but no one has actually said that $m,n$ must be integers. So it's not impossible at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't. Yes, it is the same as equating coefficients. Any non-zero polynomial over a field has only finite roots, and so does $(3-m)x+(2-n)y$. If this equals zero for every real number, that means it has infinite solutions, and thus is the zero polynomial (the one whose coefficients are all zero). The proof of this theorem is usually done by induction on the polynomial's degree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
$$3x+2y=mx+ny$$

$$  (x,y)=(1,1) \implies m+n=5$$
$$  (x,y)=(1,-1) \implies m-n=1$$

Solve for $m$ and $n$, you get $m=3$, $n=2.$